# While using JWT module i am getting an error "user does not exists error"

Tags: python, authentication, jwt, token, tokenize

I am learning simple python JWT module. I am creating a token using restfull api and then using the same token to get the data, But unfortunately i am getting an error "User does not exist".
[image: See the way i am getting token]

[image: The way i am authenticating the user]

Python Code snippet

```
    class User:
    def __init__(self, _id, username, password):
        self.id = _id
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

users = [
    User(1, "bob", "asdf")
]


username_mapping = {u.username: u for u in users}

userid_mapping = {u.id: u for u in users}


def authenticate(username, password):
    user = username_mapping.get(username, None)
    if user and user.password == password:
        return user


def identity(payload):
    user_id = payload["identity"]
    return username_mapping.get(user_id, None)
```

##Using this function for authentication

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "jose"
api = Api(app)
jwt = JWT(app,authenticate, identity)


def abort_if_item_not_exist(name):
item = next(filter(lambda x: x["name"] == name, items), None)
if item == None:
    abort(404, message = "This item does not exist")
else:
        return {"item": item}


class Item(Resource):
    @jwt_required()
    def get(self,name):
        return abort_if_item_not_exist(name)
```

Comment: can you post please add the token to the question? And show the code with which you create it

Comment: Have you tried inserting your token in Postman by going to Authorisation->Type->Bearer Token and copy paste your token in the "Token" right box?

Comment: Yes, i tried "Bearer Token" it is giving me an error "Unsupported authorization type"

Comment: token is there in screen shot, and every time it will generate new token when i authenticate.
JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MDIwNjY5NTcsImlhdCI6MTYwMjA2NjY1NywibmJmIjoxNjAyMDY2NjU3LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6MX0.MH5Go-w1A4oO3q7SxUHAKxZT1wWYKf1T1MYK8X2x8sw

Comment: I have seen the screenshot, but I can't decode a token in my head by just looking at it, I wanted to inspect it on https://jwt.io/  to see what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, thanks to [jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7329832/jps), he pointed a website. I analyzed and got the payload identity id. Then I realized I am getting an ID and I am comparing it with wrong value. it is my typo only.

```
def identity(payload):
user_id = payload["identity"]
return userid_mapping.get(user_id, None) # This needs to be changed
```